# Unable to power up systemd service

Tags: systemd, daemon

I just got everything set and done with my python flask project and I would like to make a service out of it.

In order to get started, I've made a bash file which is supposed to start the server and can be located in /home/pi

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/pi/Desktop/secure-pi-tensorflow
python3 /home/pi/Desktop/secure-pi-tensorflow/run.py
```

My service file looks like this:

```
[Unit]
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=idle
ExecStart=/home/pi/securepi.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The problem that I am facing is that I am able to power up the server with the bash file, but it doesn't start as a service, this error pops up:

```
pi@securepi:~ $ systemctl status securepi.service
Warning: The unit file, source configuration file or drop-ins of securepi.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.
● securepi.service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/securepi.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2019-10-28 15:42:39 GMT; 8min ago
  Process: 1325 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Desktop/secure-pi-tensorflow/run.py (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 1325 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Oct 28 15:42:38 securepi systemd[1]: Started securepi.service.
Oct 28 15:42:39 securepi python3[1325]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Oct 28 15:42:39 securepi python3[1325]:   File "/home/pi/Desktop/secure-pi-tensorflow/run.py", line 12, in <module>
Oct 28 15:42:39 securepi python3[1325]:     from securepi import app
Oct 28 15:42:39 securepi python3[1325]:   File "/home/pi/Desktop/secure-pi-tensorflow/securepi/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
Oct 28 15:42:39 securepi python3[1325]:     from flask_jsglue import JSGlue
Oct 28 15:42:39 securepi python3[1325]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_jsglue'
Oct 28 15:42:39 securepi systemd[1]: securepi.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 28 15:42:39 securepi systemd[1]: securepi.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Does anybody have any idea what's going on with that error? Everything runs just fine when powered by the bash file but always fails when the service tries

Also I would like to mention that the **flask_jsglue** in installed for both python2.7 and 3

```
pi@securepi:~ $ python3
Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr  3 2019, 05:39:12) 
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import flask_jsglue
[2]+  Stopped                 python3
pi@securepi:~ $ python
Python 2.7.16 (default, Apr  6 2019, 01:42:57) 
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import flask_jsglue
```

Comment: How did you install `flask_jsglue` ? Via `pip` or with your package manager?

Comment: I used pip3 to install it

Comment: maybe it's the user that's running it?

Comment: how could I check that?

Comment: If the module is installed in `/usr/lib/pythonx.y/site-packages`, it should be visible by all users. Otherwise, I think we have an anwer.

Comment: all right so I found out that If I add User=pi in service it works just fine, but how could I possibly make this global for all users?

Comment: Is the service meant to be run by the system or the individual users? a) put it in `/etc/systemd/system/` and enable via `systemctl enable securepi.service` otherwise b) in `/etc/systemd/user/` and run `systemctl --user --global enable securepi.service`.  Set `User=pi` in service if need be and make sure users may run the command as that user (in case b). [Reference on `--system` vs `--user`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User) .

Comment: my current location is in /lib/systemd/system. might that be the reason?

Comment: Feel free to add an answer to your own question! (once you figure it all out)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was to add User=pi to fix this.

Comment: What/where did you add the User=pi?

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add your system user (pi or ubuntu for instance) in the [Service] section of the /etc/systemd/system/my_service.service file:

```
[Unit]
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=idle
ExecStart=/home/pi/securepi.sh
User=your_system_user

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```